# What is the duty of webpack.mix.js in Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am beginner in Laravel and what I want to understand is what is the duty of webpack.mix.js with its function mix.js. I have searched so many sites and could not find any that clearly explains this topic

Comment: Clearly you didn't search the official Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: @thefallen, I have searched this site but the role of webpack.mix.js was explained superficially

Comment: This is the file where you define all the laravel-mix compilations and webpack related code, nothing more to explain.

Comment: @thefallen, look dude, I hope you do not mind if I ask question from you. As it is clear to me so far is mix.js in webpack.mix.js just compiles all file from app.js and puts it inside public/app.js. Meaning it gets all the filefrom one place and places into another. Right?

Comment: If you want to know more about `mix`: https://laravel-mix.com/

Comment: From @thefallen's link: "_Laravel Mix provides a fluent API for defining Webpack build steps for your Laravel application using several common CSS and JavaScript pre-processors._". Depending on what you add to your `webpack.mix.js` if you run `npm run watch` your `.scss` files get compiled into `app.scss`, it can copy files to different folders (images etc.) and compiles your `app.js`. And if you want to know more about webpack: https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: @kerbholz, I really appreciate that you paid attention to my question. So, what I understood so far is mix.js is what takes all information from app.js and app.scss and then send that information to public/js and public/css so that we can use that information from public folder. Am I right? I mean mix.js plays role of middleman takes code from one place and put it into public so that we developers can use. I hope you will answer. Thank you in advance

Comment: `webpack` does all the work of copying/compiling your files, `mix` is just a different way to write webpack instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `php artisan preset none|vue|bootstrap` (just one of them)

This is explained better in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend

And then an npm install, artisan and npm will create the necessary scaffold for starting your project.

webpack.mix.js is where you compile your js.

Example if you run

```
php artisan preset vue

npm install && npm run dev
```

you would have the necessary scaffolding for vue

if you dont make a spa and you have various VUE.js apps, you can compile all of them by adding them to the webpack.mix.js file...

You can also compile your css, and scss from here.

i think thats a very simple explanation. Of course i recommend you follow the links provided in the comments to dig deeper.

Comment: hey dude Erubiel how you doing, honestly, you have helped me to understand so much info about Laravel previously and now also that I just do not know how to thank you :). So what I try to understand is, all right, we have webpack.mix.js with mix.js inside and I wonder what the mix.js does, I know, it compiles all the code and packets from app.js and app.scss and then puts it inside public folder Right? Meaning mix.js plays role of just middleman that collects all info and then sends to public folder we can use then Right? Sorry for so many words :)

Comment: At the end of the day what you accomplish with webpack.mix.js you could accomplish with webpack.js alone, webpack.mix.js can be see as a wrapper to simplify the usage of webpack for the laravel programmer..